# Unable to add UEFI entry on my HP laptop

Tags: linux, boot, bios, uefi

Ever since I have removed Ubuntu from my HP 15s-eq247ng Laptop and installed Debian on it, I had issues with the boot entries. It had kept the Ubuntu entries in the beginning until one day I must've forcefully got rid of them.

Currently, the EFI files for GRUB *exist*, but I have to interrupt the boot every time to select the correct file. I have tried to fix this issue with `efibootmgr` and it looked like it fixed it, until I rebooted my computer. **It looks like this issue is most commonly related to dual-boot environments. There is, however, just one operating system installed on my machine. Also, secure boot is greyed out and on disabled for me.**

This is what I tried:

```
root:~# efibootmgr
Timeout: 0 seconds
BootOrder: 0001,0002,9999
Boot0001* USB Network Adapter (IPv4 UEFI) - PXE IPv4 Realtek USB Ethernet Controller
Boot0002* USB Network Adapter (IPv6 UEFI) - PXE IPv6 Realtek USB Ethernet Controller
Boot9999* USB Drive (UEFI)
root:~# 
root:~# lsblk 
NAME        MAJ:MIN RM   SIZE RO TYPE MOUNTPOINTS
nvme0n1     259:0    0 476,9G  0 disk 
├─nvme0n1p1 259:1    0   512M  0 part /boot/efi
├─nvme0n1p2 259:2    0 475,5G  0 part /
└─nvme0n1p3 259:3    0   976M  0 part [SWAP]
root:~# tree /boot/efi/
/boot/efi/
└── EFI
    └── debian
        ├── BOOTX64.CSV
        ├── fbx64.efi
        ├── grub.cfg
        ├── grubx64.efi
        ├── mmx64.efi
        └── shimx64.efi

3 directories, 6 files
root:~# efibootmgr -c -d /dev/nvme0n1 -l \\EFI\\debian\\grubx64.efi
Timeout: 0 seconds
BootOrder: 0000,0001,0002,9999
Boot0001* USB Network Adapter (IPv4 UEFI) - PXE IPv4 Realtek USB Ethernet Controller
Boot0002* USB Network Adapter (IPv6 UEFI) - PXE IPv6 Realtek USB Ethernet Controller
Boot9999* USB Drive (UEFI)
Boot0000* Linux
root:~#
```

Here's some additional system information in case you need it:

###### BIOS

| Label | Data |
| --- | --- |
| Product name | 15s-eq2xx |
| System Family | HP Notebook |
| BIOS Vendor | AMI |
| BIOS Revision | F.03 |
| Device Firmware Revision / Embedded Controller | 59.08 |
| Device Firmware Revision / GOP (Graphic Output Protocol) | 2.14.0 |
| Factory installed OS | non-Windows UEFI |

###### Debian

| Label | Data |
| --- | --- |
| Version | 12 (Bookworm) |
| Type | 64 bit |